# UML Meta-object properties

Tags: uml

I try to understand OMG UML specs. I need to create meta-object that will be parent for all objects.

I understand that each UML object has these properties:

- Name
- Package
- ID
- Visibility
- Stereotype
- Parent
- Comments

Is it all? Or am I missing something.

Comment: By create you mean implement the UML meta-model?

Comment: There is nothing called "UML object". So what actually do you mean?

Comment: All UML elements (entities, objects) has some attributes (properties), I need find common for all these entities

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I think we are people, it's logically that I called elementary entity of UML

Comment: You can start with `Figure 7.1 Root`, especially with the `Element` class which is close to your "_UML object_"

Comment: Thank you! I try to understand it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CommonStructure::Element` which can be considered "*UML object*" does not expose too many useful attributes as you can see by reading
http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20131001/UML.xmi, package `CommonStructure`

[image]

<sub>(Diagram created with Enterprise Architect)</sub>

Comment: You can download the meta model from OMG and import it in EA: http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/